# redsocks within private network

Tags: iptables, proxy, lan

Is it possible for redsocks to capture traffic within the LAN/Same subnet/private network. I need to proxy ALL the outgoing tcp traffic from a Linux device. The device, proxy server and target server are all in the same network.
I get "redsocks.c:638 redsocks_accept_client(...) accept: out of file descriptors, backing off for XXX ms: Too many open file" message continuously.

```
base{log_debug=on;
log_info=on;
log="file:redsocks.log";
daemon=on;
redirector=iptables;
}

redsocks{
local_ip=127.0.0.1;
local_port=31338;
ip=10.48.130.34;
port=8889;
type=socks5;
}


iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 31338
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting the open file limit. You can check what it is using `ulimit -n` (probably 1024) and set a higher limit, for example 10'000, using `ulimit -n 10000`.